# Content Database Restore Failing

Tags: content-database, restore

Can anyone point me a direction to solve this issue?

> Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 5.
>
> Login failed for user 'Domain\Administrator'. Reason: Could not find a
>   login matching the name provided. [CLIENT: ]  Error:
>   18456, Severity: 14, State: 5.  Login failed for user
>   'Domain\Administrator'. Reason: Could not find a login matching the
>   name provided. [CLIENT: 10.0.0.244]  Error: 18456, Severity: 14,
>   State: 5.  Login failed for user 'Domain\Administrator'. Reason: Could
>   not find a login matching the name provided. [CLIENT: 10.0.0.244]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be because you were using the Domain\Administrator for the local domain and that account is not valid for the domain you are restoring to. you can either drop the user from the actual domain  and backup the database or create user account in the environment where the database is restored to. Refer to the following post for more information

[Login Failed for user](http://stevemannspath.blogspot.com/2014/06/sharepoint-2013-login-failed-for-user.html)

[Restoring SCCM Site cannot connect to SQL database](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5cd2cca2-4ff6-4c5b-94e7-b073c61e451d/restoring-sccm-site-cannot-connect-to-sql-database?forum=configmanagerdeployment)

Answer (score 2):

Try running SSMS on the server with 'Run As Admin' to check if you added builtin\administrators during install. If you cant find any user with enough rights then you have to add a login to the server and give it sysadmin rights.